# How to set umask for a folder and it's subfolder?

Tags: debian, umask

I'm working on the same directory with some friends and they access it via SSH.

I added us in the same group and defined a sticky bit to keep the user:group values the same.

But when a user create a file/folder, the Write attribute is not defined for the group, disabling other to write it/on it.

How can I define the Umask to add the Write value for groups in the specific directory and it's subfolders ?

I tried to find some help before, but I only saw helps for Fedora/CentOs, and I'm using Debian  Squeeze.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you did already:

```
chmod g+rwxs directory
```

and now you have to make sure that the users have a umask like 002.
To setup the umask for all the users, try in /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile.

***caveat***: you cannot setup a umask per directory as it's a process level thing.

Interesting read http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Thanks for this help. Does it works when using ssh over git ?

Comment: tbh I am not sure but, because you are using a unix user anyway even with git, in theory it should work.

Comment: You actually can set a umask per directory using Linux ACLs, e.g. use `setfacl -R -m group:groupname:rw-,d:group:groupname:rw- directory/` to force the r and w permission for the group "groupname" on a directory

Comment: On "you cannot setup a umask per directory as it's a process level thing.": Eventually it's a filesystem (I mean VFS) thing, and a filesystem *could* do that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a comprehensive example using ***setfacl*** which gives you that granular control you requested on a per-directory basis where new files will be created with the write attribute for the group:

1. Create the group that will own the shared folder:

   ```
   sudo addgroup projects
   ```
2. Create the folder "*project1*" we want to share in an appropriate FHS path such as ***/srv***:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /srv/project1
   ```
3. Change ownership of the shared ***folder*** "*project1*" to ***group*** "*projects*":

   ```
   sudo chown root:projects /srv/project1
   ```
4. Set the mode on the folder to be be writable to group members, but only allow the owner to delete their own files:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 1775 /srv/project1
   ```
5. Add your users to the group "*projects*":

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G projects user1
   sudo usermod -a -G projects user2
   ```
6. Users must log-out and log back in to recognize the new group memberships
7. Finally, apply `setfacl` so all new files are created writable by group members:

   ```
   sudo setfacl -d -m group:projects:rwx /srv/project1
   ```

Users can now edit each other's files. In terms of managing group documents, a versioning system such as Git is going to be a better solution

Comment: Can you explain whether (and if so: *how*) it works for sub-folders (as requested)?

Answer (score 0):

The umask is an attribute of a user's environment (more specifically, a process) rather than a directory.  So each of the users sharing that directory should add the following `umask` command to their `~/.profile`:

```
umask 002
```

This will make files they create group-writeable by default.

Comment: umask 002 ~ chomd 775

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa Actually `umask 002` corresponds to `chmod o-w`; that's not the same as  `chmod ug=rwx,o=rx`. Try creating a text file and see the difference.