# How to have a shared folder on a Linux system where all files within are rwx to everyone and all new files are rwx by everyone?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I want to have a shared folder on my system that will be used by all users as a place to put files and executibles.

I have created a folder and given it `rwx` to everyone - but whenever a new user adds something the new item has restrictive permissions

```
$ sudo mkdir /dmz
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /dmz
$ touch /dmz/foo
$ ls -l /dmz
-rw-r--r--. 1 alshdavid alshdavid 0 Jun  3 10:07 foo
```

I am using Fedora (I am not sure if distros make a difference with this). Is there a way to have this folder grant permissive rules for all users?

Alternatively, I'm still pretty new the the idea of groups, if I made a `dmz` group and manually added my users to that group, could new files in that folder be given `rwx` for members of the group?

Comment: Please provide the output of “umask -s”, simplest solution, would be to change the umask value and then assign all new users to the same group with useradd and existing users with usermod

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dmz`, where `a` means "all" (users). Or `sudo chmod ugo+rwx /dmz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was set a umask using these instructions: [How to set umask for a folder and it's subfolder?](https://superuser.com/questions/612771/how-to-set-umask-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolder)

```bash
sudo groupadd dmz
sudo mkdir /dmz
sudo chmod -R 1775 /dmz
sudo chown root:dmz /dmz
sudo setfacl -d -m group:dmz:rwx /dmz


sudo usermod -a -G dmz user1
sudo usermod -a -G dmz user2
```